# How to align multiple pie charts side by side?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am pretty new to HTML5.  I use Chart.js generating 3 Pie charts, but they display vertically. What I want get is align those 3 charts side by side horizontally.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

[image]

```
<div id="aligned">
  <div class="label">Aligned</div>
  <div class="chart_container">
     <canvas  id="myChart" width="300px" height="200px"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="chart_container">
    <canvas  id="myChart2" width="300px" height="200px"></canvas>
  </div>

      <div class="chart_container">
    <canvas  id="myChart1" width="300px" height="100px"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make them an in-line element.

Div's aren't usually in-line elements so either change the div to an in-line element or alter the div in the css.

```
  display: inline-block;
```

Please provide a jsfiddle if you want more guidance.